# Error creating toast on Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, notifications, windows-10, toast

Platform my application - Windows 8.1.
On Windows 8.1 - no error.
On Windows 10 - error: "Invalid application ID."
Code:

```
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

or

```
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(a).Show(toast);
```

Write to that location "a"?...

Does not work *Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.Name* or *Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FullName*...

Sorry for my English...

Comment: What's the platform of your app? Is your app a Windows 8.1 Store app or a  UWP app or a classic desktop app?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Store app

Comment: Do you have the same `Invalid application ID.` error when you use `ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);`?

Comment: Yes. I understood! The error occurs in the background task, otherwise all is well... Background task - a separate project that is marked as "portable" (... I have russian version Visual Studio).

Comment: For a background task, we need use a Windows Runtime Component, not a Portable Class Library. Please check it. Besides, I've built a simple background task with using `ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);`, it works well.  For a Windows 8.1 Store app, we can just use `ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier()` method. `ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(String)` is used if your app uses a background voice-over-Internet protocol (VOIP) agent. If you still have errors, please share a sample that can reproduce your issue, so that we can help you further.